# being prompted for ssh-password by ansible in easy_install

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-facts

Team, 
I need to use dig module which my macbook complains dnspython needed. so am installing it with easy_install but am getting prompted for password. How to make it passwordless?

```
      - easy_install:
          name: dnspython
          state: present
        become: yes

      - name: Validate DNS record lookup for {{ kubeapi_server }}
        debug: msg="{{ lookup('dig', '{{ kubeapi_server }}' )}}"
        vars:
          variable: "{{ lookup('dig', '{{ kubeapi_server }}' )}}"
        failed_when: not variable
```

output1: with -k option

```
ansible-playbook -i inventory.txt playbook.yaml -k -K
SSH password: 
BECOME password[defaults to SSH password]:
```

output1: without -k -K option

```
ansible-playbook -i inventory.txt playbook.yaml
```

```
TASK [0_test : easy_install] ***************************
fatal: [target1]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "error: can't create or remove files in install directory\n\nThe following error occurred while trying to add or remove files in the\ninstallation directory:\n\n    [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/test-easy-install-68421.pth'\n\nThe installation directory you specified (via --install-dir, --prefix, or\nthe distutils default setting) was:\n\n    /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/\n\nPerhaps your account does not have write access to this directory?  If the\ninstallation directory is a system-owned directory, you may need to sign in\nas the administrator or \"root\" account.  If you do not have administrative\naccess to this machine, you may wish to choose a different installation\ndirectory, preferably one that is listed in your PYTHONPATH environment\nvariable.\n\nFor information on other options, you may wish to consult the\ndocumentation at:\n\n  https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/easy_install.html\n\nPlease make the appropriate changes for your system and try again.\n\n"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Possible causes could be:
1. You didn't specified password in inventory of host machine.
2. sudo permission of the user should be NOPASSWD: ALL in /etc/sudoers of the host machine.